# How to disabling core dumps of all JAVA processes

Tags: java, centos, centos7, rhel7

I have a RHEL linux OS installed and Java installed. I would like to know if there is a way to disable all the coredumps from Java from platform/OS front.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-disable-core-dumps/

Comment: You can use **`-XX:-CreateCoredumpOnCrash`** when your application is using JDK 9 and above.